# 403 redirect doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-403

How to force apache to redirect to a 403 error?
I've tried:

```
RewriteRule ^forbid/(.*)$ / [R=403,L]
```

this caused 500 server error on the whole site

```
RewriteRule ^forbid/(.*)$ - [R=403,L]
```

and

```
RewriteRule ^forbid/(.*)$ [R=403,L]
```

these simply don't work

I have the following .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(config|backup)(.*)$ - [F] [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ /admin/index.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L,QSA] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !util
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L,QSA]
```

Please, help me!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^forbid/(.*)$ - [F]
```

Source: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_f

Comment: Yup. Redirects only live in the `3xx` code range, `403 Forbidden` is a client error, not a redirect.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a `RewriteBase` defined that we don't see in your rules, I think you don't want the `^` before 'forbid' your expression, since it would technically start with '/'

```
RewriteRule ^forbid/(.*)$ - [R=403,L]
# Instead try
RewriteRule ^/forbid/(.*)$ - [R=403,L]
# Or
RewriteRule forbid/(.*)$ - [R=403,L]
```

Comment: actually, I have RewriteBase, but I forgot to copy that. But anyway this doesn't make any sense.