# htaccess + mod_rewrite: deny access to non existent folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a Wordpress installation that uses permalinks, using mod_rewrite:

```
mysite.com/wp/post?id=3 becomes mysite.com/cats/furrycat
```

Now I want to prevent visitors to see posts in `mysite.com/notes/`. This folder does not exist, as it's just a wordpress category.

**How can I block access to `/notes/` in the root .htaccess?**

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/a/6032162/1810128 

    RewriteRule ^notes/(.*)$ - [F]

Comment: Why not use `<Location /notes/>\n Order deny,allow\n     Deny from all\n </Location>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Above** the wordpress rules in the htaccess file in your document root, add:

```
RewriteRule ^notes/ - [L,F]
```

These need to be in the file before any of the wordpress rules. This will return a 403 Forbidden if a request is made that starts with `/notes/`